# How do I compare a file and if it exists

Tags: python

So I'm messing with reading/writing files.

I have this right now

```
name = input("To create a file, you must name it. /n What do you want to name your file?")
f = open(name, 'w')
```

How do I compare the name of the file to existing files in that folder and if that file exists prompt user if they want to overwrite or not?

Comment: You can use os.path module to identify the file is already exist or not i.e. os.path.isfile(file_name) will return true and false

Answer (score 1):

You can check for file existence using:

```
os.path.exists(name)
```

However, you'd still have to specify the directory you want the file to be in.

Edit: for example by using:

```
os.getcwd()
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `os.path.exists()` and/or `os.stat()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check using:

os.path.isfile(path)

It will Return True if path is an existing regular file.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, os.path.exists() will successfully do it. Even then, I still recommend using a with statement when opening and closing files. It's much more foolproof. Here's an example of how you can implement this:

```
import os

name = input("To create a file, you must name it.\nWhat do you want to name your file? ")
file_path = name  # Assuming the file is in the current directory

if os.path.exists(file_path):
    overwrite_choice = input("File already exists. Do you want to overwrite it? (yes/no): ").lower()
    if overwrite_choice == 'yes':
        with open(file_path, 'w') as f:
            # Perform operations on the file
            print(f"File '{name}' has been overwritten.")
    else:
        print("File was not overwritten.")
else:
    with open(file_path, 'w') as f:
        # Perform operations on the file
        print(f"File '{name}' has been created.")
```

Keep in mind the formatted strings only works on python 3.6 and above.